# Cell with background text that disappears when clicked

Tags: excel

I want to create cells which instruct the user on what need to be filled in that cell in the background and when you click to enter a something, this text vanishes. You normally see this you order something online. For example: Question: Date of Birth, answer field: DD/MM/YYYY in grey text. When you click on DD/MM/YYYY it dissappears and you can answer.

I would like to do this without using VBA, since I have no experience using VBA. Is this possible?

I thought about using conditional formatting, but I think the text won't disappear when clicked only when someone types something in.

Anyone has any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Doesn't look like it can be done without VBA.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks for taking the time though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can enter placeholder text like cell value and colour it grey.

[image: Before insert]

Then you can use `Conditional Formatting` to turn it black if new text is different than placeholder.
[image]
[image]

This would be the result:

[image]

However if you wan to make sure that your input is correct I suggest using `Data Validation`.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, since the text will still be there after a click, but I think it's the closest possible solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are also some VBA workarounds, but you didn't want that either and some issues might occur.